# Google maps giving 403 when switching from http to https

Tags: google-maps

I was able to successfully show the google maps on [this page](https://www.koloden.com/contact.ms) when the url was only http , now I after making it as https , it is giving errors like :
**NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - [https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d41.88098829471135&2d-87.65924221147355&2m2&1d41.88841667852121&2d-87.6252154211187&2u17&4sen-US&5e0&6sm%40347000000&7b0&8e0&9b0&callback=*xdc*._1eql41&token=45632](https://maps-api-ssl.google.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d41.88098829471135&2d-87.65924221147355&2m2&1d41.88841667852121&2d-87.6252154211187&2u17&4sen-US&5e0&6sm%40347000000&7b0&8e0&9b0&callback=_xdc_._1eql41&token=45632)**

Any suggestions on what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you using Google Maps API premium plan ?

Comment: no, its not premium

Comment: Ok do one thing , generate a new API key and use it , it will work I guess . Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: maps-api-ssl.google.com seems to be outdated. You can use the https://maps.googleapis.com/

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#WebServices), your http request should look more like this: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/service/output?parameters`. [HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/overview#SSL) is required for all Maps API web service requests containing user data, or developer identifiers. Requests made over HTTP that include sensitive data may be rejected.

Found also in this [HTTP and HTTPS protocols are considered different URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#registering-authorized-urls) documentation that if **HTTPS** is authorized, **HTTP** is not necessarily authorized. If you'd like to authorize both at once, you may add a domain without using a protocol: `example.com/`.

A [403 Forbidden error](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/403-forbidden-or-no-permission-to-access) means that you do not have permission to view the requested file or resource. While sometimes this is intentional, other times it is due to misconfigured permissions.

> [Why am I receiving a HTTP 403 Forbidden response to my Maps API web
>   service
>   requests?](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/faq#url_signing)
>
> An HTTP 403 response indicates a permission issue, likely because the
>   signature could not be verified for this request. This could be
>   because:
>
> - A signature has been specified but is incorrect for this request.
> - The request specifies a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID but does not specify a signature, and the web service being called
>     requires that all requests made using a client ID include a valid
>     signature.
> - A signature has been specified but the associated Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID has not been specified.

Hope this helps!